# signature API to createEnvelope to preload data for standard fields

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign signature API for embedded signing.
While creating envelope I am using API [https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountid}/envelopes](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7Baccountid%7D/envelopes) I am using composite template to set values for tabs.

As per docusign documentation we can not set values for some standard type fields.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/#tab-types

But as per API webinar which I attended, it has been confirmed in call that we can set values for standard type fields companyTabs, titleTabs etc.

Can you please check my REQUEST data and help me to understand what is missing in this API request.

Below is a request for createEnvelope API

REQUEST

```
{
    "emailSubject": "event registration waiver",
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "templateId": "a975e665-f0c1********3268f3fb0d19"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "retyvoz@mailinator.com",
                                "name": "Phillip Emerson",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "clientUserId": "1000",
                                "roleName": "Tester",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "textTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "Newtest",
                                            "value": "Phillip Emerson"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "companyTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "tabId": "aaa640c1********-5affa8148b06",
                                            "value": "Google"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "sequence": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Response

Envelope is getting created but data for standard field Company is not getting set to value "Google" whereas textTab value gets set.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your question. ***Many thanks!***

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/#tab-types) the `company` tab type can't be set by the developer.

Instead, use a text tab.

Comment: I had attended their API webnir and there they said we can set values for company tab as well.

Comment: You can't change the company value per envelope. Either you misunderstood the webinar speaker or vice versa. Read the docs